# How to scrape NHL skater stats using Xpath?

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to scrape the stats for 2017/2018 NHL skaters. I have started on the code but I am running into issues parsing the data and printing to excel.

Here is my code so far:

```
#import modules 

from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring

import pandas as pd

#connect to url

url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2018_skaters.html"

#remove HTML comment markup

content = str(urlopen(url).read())
comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
tree = fromstring(comment)

#setting up excel columns

columns = ("names", "gp", "g", "s", "team")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)    

#attempt at parsing data while using loop    

for nhl, skater_row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]/tr')):
    names = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
    gp = skater_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="games_played"]/text()')[0]
    g = skater_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="goals"]/text()')[0]
    s = skater_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="shots"]/text()')[0]
    try:
        team = skater_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="team_id"]/a')[0].text

    # create pandas dataframe to export data to excel

    df.loc[nhl] = (names, team, gp, g, s)

#write data to excel

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NHL skater.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Can someone please explain how to parse this data? Are there any tips you have to help write the Xpath so I can loop through the data?

I am having trouble writing the line:

```
for nhl, skater_row in enumerate(tree.xpath...
```

How did you find the Xpath? Did you use Xpath Finder or Xpath Helper?

Also, I ran into an error with the line:

```
df.loc[nhl] = (names, team, gp, g, s)
```

It shows an invalid syntax for df.

I am new to web scraping and have no prior experience coding. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to stick to XPath and get required data only instead of filtering complete data, you can try below:

```
for row in tree.xpath('//table[@id="stats"]/tbody/tr[not(@class="thead")]'):
    name = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]')[0].text_content()
    gp = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="games_played"]')[0].text_content()
    g = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="goals"]')[0].text_content()
    s = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="shots"]')[0].text_content()
    team = row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="team_id"]')[0].text_content()
```

Output of `print(name, gp, g, s, team)`:

```
Justin Abdelkader 75 13 110 DET
Pontus Aberg 53 4 70 TOT
Pontus Aberg 37 2 39 NSH
Pontus Aberg 16 2 31 EDM
Noel Acciari 60 10 66 BOS
Kenny Agostino 5 0 11 BOS
Sebastian Aho 78 29 200 CAR
...
```

Comment: Beautiful work @Andersson! This code is flawless... Thank you sir =)

Comment: Any advice on writing the line: tr[not(@class="thead")] @Andersson? Just curious how you came up with that.

Comment: @AbleArcher there is a header row after each 20 player rows. So to exclude those rows from selection and get entries with players only you need to add `[not(@class="thead")]` predicate

Comment: That makes perfect sense @Andersson... Thanks again for your knowledge and expertise!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC: It can be done like this with [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and `pandas` [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

```
import requests
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2018_skaters.html'
pg = requests.get(url)
bsf = BeautifulSoup(pg.content, 'html5lib')
tables = bsf.findAll('table', attrs={'id':'stats'})
dfs = pd.read_html(tables[0].prettify())
df = dfs[0]
```

The resultant dataframe will have all the columns in the table and use pandas to filter the columns that are required.

```
#Filters only columns 1, 3 and 5 similarly all required columns can be filtered.
dff = df[df.columns[[1, 3, 5]]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Abbas for your time! Amazing! I was hoping to use the Xpath but this seems more than sufficient.